# Keyboard layouts in ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, gnome, c++, c

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome fallback mode (compiz), the input sources in Text Entry are English and Russian.

How can I get these layouts programmatically or at least in the console?

I tried XkbGetNames and got the following results:

> console in English: return only English
>   console in Russian : return English, Russian

I got the same result with `./xkblayout-state print "%N"` and `setxkbmap -query | grep layout`.

My main problem is if the console is in English, it is not returning both layouts, why and how do I fix it!